# which is the better way of coding

Tags: java

Might seem like a silly question. I just wanted to know which is better way of coding.

Option 1:

```
if(a==null) {
    a=getA();
    return a;
} else {
    return a;
}
```

Option 2:

```
if(a==null) {
    a=getA();
}
return a;
```

variable a is a static variable used to cache the getA() and avoid calling it multiple times.

Comment: Did you forget the condition in the second example?

Comment: yea sorry....i have added it

Comment: Seems to be mostly opinion based (i would prefer option 2)

Comment: There is no "best" way of coding, but since the second code does basicly the same with less code, i´d go with the second one. But you should allways check the code for readability, which in my eyes is more important then less code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a 3rd alternative which is even shorter - using the ternary conditional operator :

```
return a != null ? a : getA();
```

EDIT: I assumed `a` is a local variable, and therefore doesn't have to be assigned if it's `null`. If, on the other hand, it's an instance variable used as a cache (to avoid calling `getA()` multiple times), you need to assign the result of `getA()` to `a`, in which case I'd use your second alternative, since it's shorter, and thus clearer (you can still use the ternary conditional operator with assignment - `return a != null ? a : (a = getA());` - but I find that less clear).

Comment: I think this will always call getA() method. getA() is a huge method and takes lots of resources and always returns same output.

Comment: No, that's not true: only one alternative in the ternary conditional is evaluated in Java. (Cf. the `iif` in VB6 which evaluates both sides.)

Comment: Though I like this style, it maybe important to note that the value of getA() was stored in the initial request, but not in this solution. We don't know where a comes for, nor what it is used for later.

Comment: @cvesters Yes, I added a comment regarding that.

Comment: This might make sense if there were no relation between getA and a, but getA to me seems like a instance instantiator of a.  This sort of logic should be pushed into getA and not made to look nicer in a ternary operator for each call to getA.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second choice as there is only one `return` statement, and this can help debugging (you only need to put in one breakpoint rather than two). Also you're arguably duplicating code in the first choice.

But in this instance I'd prefer using the ternary conditional:

`return a == null ? getA() : a;`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second option, The best practice is have only one return statement in a method. That will be the more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

The second is more concise, and could be better because of this, but this is a subjective matter and no-one can give you a particularly objective answer. Whatever you like or fits into your teams coding standards is the answer.

As has been pointed out, there is a shorter way to do this:

```
return a!=null ? a : getA();
```

but again, it entirely depends on what you and your team prefer. Personally I prefer the second way you showed to this, as it is more readable (in my opinion).

Comment: but it doesn't store the value of getA() if i'm not wrong. calling getA() everytime is waste of resource

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming for a second that `a` is a class member and that `getA()` is a method that creates an instance of `a`.

The best solution should be to push this logic in the called method.  In other words, rather than have:

```
void someFunction() {
    // logic
    if(a==null) {
        a=getA();
    }
    return a;
}

A getA() {
    // creation logic of instance A
    return newAInstance;
}
```

You should have:

```
void someFunction() {
    // logic

    return getA();
}

A getA() {
    if(a == null) {
        // creation logic of instance A
    }
    return a;
}
```

The cost of the method call is minimal and worth not having to deal with *when* `a` will be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but i dont have the access to modify getA() method.FYI, the getA() method actually gives me a huge hashmap.

Comment: @NitishVasu You could wrap the A class in your own class that will call super.getA() only if it isn't already loaded.  Consider it.  ;)